# How does blood react to heat when inside the body

Tags: hematology, blood-circulation

I was wondering:

What are the possible dangers of being burned on the surface of the skin. 
Does it congeal (that's what my intuition tells me)? At which temperature would that happen? How heat-conductive is human flesh?

On the other hand, there's of course been many cases of severely burned people who did obviously not die afterwards.

This question comes from an argument i had the other day, when a friend burned himself by accident and we got into talking about what was actually happening with the affected blood (i.e. at the wrists, neck etc) and if it is dangerous (if you could actually die from an occasion where you burned yourself and then get a stroke or something)